# unable to send large files to Kafka broker | Error message: The request included a message larger than the max message size the server will accept

Tags: apache-kafka

I am unable to send large file to the broker, I have edited the configuration files and inside my client program but it didn't work.

- Error Message

  The request included a message larger than the max message size the server will accept.
- Server properties

  ```
  message.max.bytes=900000000
  replica.fetch.max.bytes=900000000
  ```
- Producer

  ```
  max.request.size=100000000
  ```
- Consumer

  ```
  max.partition.fetch.bytes=100000000
  fetch.message.max.bytes=100000000
  ```
- Client app

  ```
  props.put("max.request.size",96214400);
  props.put("message.max.bytes",96214400);
  ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving comment to answer...

The [message.max.bytes](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html#message.max.bytes) is a cluster-wide setting and you need to make sure that the corresponding [max.message.bytes](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html#max.message.bytes) configuration is also set at topic-level. As the topic-level configuration defaults to `1048588` you are seeing this error.

Answer (score 2):

```
kafka-topics.bat --create --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test --config max.message.bytes=9000000
```